# How to execute Angular Expressions values in Directives values in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to execute Angular Expressions values in Directives values in Angular Js.
**{{user.name}}** is work. But when I use it in Directive ( ng-init ), It wont work.

```
ng-init="formData.id='{{user.name}}'"
```

Or any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ngInit` directive as the name suggest, does initialization tasks, for example if you want to set an user's name and age data, you can do the following:

```
<div ng-init="user.name='John'; user.age=50">
```

This is executed before angular starts bootstrapping your app and compiling templates. Expressions surrounded by double curly braces `{{ }}` are bindings that tell angular to evaluate an expression and produce output, so if you want to display data previously initialized just add them to your document like this:

```
<body ng-app>
    <div ng-init="user.name='John'; user.age=50">
      {{user.name}} is {{user.age}} years old.
    </div>
</body>
```

​
Check the very basic example here: http://jsfiddle.net/j9Nfd/

Answer (score 3):

Directive expressions are expressions so just use

```
ng-init="formData.id = user.name"
```